# JTDS Connection problems to SQL Server - Works on 2000 but not 2005

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, jdbc

I've been trying to get a java application connecting via the jtds jdbc to a couple of SQL servers.  I have to connect via windows authentication.

The connection string specified is:

```
String connectionString = _"jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://"+server+":"+port+"/"+database+";domain="+domain;_
```

and I am getting the connection via:

```
con = java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(url, _username, _password);
```

This works fine on my SQL Server 2000 but not on the SQL Server 2005.  On my SQL Server 2005, I get the following error message:

**java.sql.SQLException: Login failed for user ''. The user is not associated with a trusted SQL Server connection.**

Looks a bit funny to be because the user in the exception is blank, but the username specified in the parameter was not blank.

I have a feeling it might be something to do with NTLM and Windows authentication because it works when I try to log using SQL authentication (ie.without the domain property)

Answer (score 0):

This occurs because SQL Server 2005/2008 has different defaults after you install them.  You still need to:

1. Open port 1433 in your Windows Firewall.
2. Enable TCP listener on port 1433 (in SQL Configuration Manager) (you can enable/disable the listener for each IP address your machine has)
3. Enable the *sa* account (or create your own SQL account)  (this also assumes you are not using integrated authentication)
4. Enable mixed authentication of your instance.

If this doesn't work, then tell us what result you get using the Microsoft JDBC driver, version 3.x or higher...